# json powershell Length of string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength Property

Tags: json, powershell

I'm using powershell with the invoke-webrequest as follows

```
$data=Invoke-webrequest -Uri <$uri> -Method Get -ContentType application/json | convertfrom-json
```

I can then interrogate this using

```
$data | select-object -expandproperty <property>
```

However using another address with a heavy payload I end up with "The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property"

After some research I changed the above to

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web.Extensions")        
$jsonserial= New-Object -TypeName System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer 
$jsonserial.MaxJsonLength  = 67108864
$Obj = $jsonserial.DeserializeObject($data)
```

I end up with $Obj that I cannot use select-object on. Not sure exactly how I can access $Obj.

Comment: You can run `$obj | Get-Member` to see what methods and properties the object has, if that's what you mean by "accessing" it.